# WCF method returns error but continues processing

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, exception, httpresponse

We have a WCF method that uses a 3rd party library to import data (through HTTP web service calls) from their servers. Our method runs in a loop and calls the library to fetch data.

The method takes a long time (over 15 minutes) to complete. Strangely, when the service runs on our production servers (but not when we run on our local servers) we see that an HTTP error code 400 is sent back to the calling Javascript even though the method *sees no exception* (we log progress and any exception to a file) and completes processing seemingly successfully - it continues to log to the file and update SQL with results from the external server even as the message is shown on the browser.

On the browser, we see the HTTP response in the Network tab, along with an ASP.NET error page (HTML) indicating indicating a bad object reference exception.

I am perplexed as to how the web method can continue even as the response has already been delivered to the browser. In an ASMX web service it is possible to send a response and still go on by using `HttpApplication.CompleteRequest`. Is there an alternative in WCF? The `WebOperationContext` class has an `OutgoingWebResponseContext` object but I don't see an option to proactively send a response back. In particular, I'm sure *our* code doesn't do any such thing - is it possible the library does?

Or could it be that a library call creates threads and one of those crashes, causing an HTTP result to be sent back even through other threads continue?

Here is the ajax code where the message is caught; the problem is of course on the server side, just wanted to show the call. The service method is complex and not illuminating.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: 'http://my-domain/service/integration.svc/ImportClients'
    headers: { 'AuthenticationGuid': getAuthenticationGuid() },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(jData),

    success: function (response, status, xhr) { alert('all good'); },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
           alert("Error\n-----\n" + xhr.status + '\n' + xhr.responseText); }
    });
```

I'm looking for insights on how to trace where the problem happens given that the code on the server runs uninterrupted. Is there a way in a WCF method to intercept the returning of the response?

Comment: Is there an error message with the status code?  When you say 'we intermittently see that an HTTP error code 400 is sent back' are you literally seeing that response _on the wire_ or are you observing it when you debug your client side code?  Could it be the case that the 3rd party library is faulting somehow and simply materializing a 400 response?

Comment: We see it over the wire: we're looking at a browser calling our service (jQuery above), and then after a while the error js alert above pops up and we see the returned 400 response in the browser Network tab. In the meantime the service continues to run.
That's what I suspect - that the library "materializes" a 400 response. But at the same time all my library calls return correctly and the service doesn't abort. How is that possible in a WCF method - form them to trigger a response without actually returning from the method? Can I intercept the sending?

Comment: If the service continues running then the service is not faulting.  My guess is that something on the client side is faulting and terminating the connection.  Since WCF does not inherently support cancellation (to my knowledge) the service will keep going even if the client disconnects.  Since you said this is a long running operation the first thing I would check is the client side timeout settings.

Comment: A couple of points:
1.  it does look indeed as if the method is not faulting
2.  but, importantly, I forgot to answer you first original question, the HTTP 400 response returned is a full ASP.NET error page (HTML) that lists an "object reference not set to a valid instance" exception, so it's not just a lost connection, it seems there was an exception *somewhere*
3. the 'intermittent' in my original post related to this never happening when we test the method on our local servers but always when we push it to our hosted production servers.

Comment: So perhaps there's some kind of an exception related to a lost connection or a timeout that originates on the server but is external to our code, and that gets reflected to the browser while the method continues to run?
Didn't think that could be possible?
Thank you so much Jason for your suggestions.